# how to get value of eclipse .classpath classpathentry

Tags: eclipse, classpath

I am writing some eclipse plugin that will do some work for BlackBerry developers.

This is the .classpath file entry of my BB project:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/net.rim.ejde.BlackBerryVMInstallType/BlackBerry JRE 5.0.0"/>
```

Using this information is it possible (programmatically) to find out the exact location of the rim plugin on the disk ?

In my case I am looking for the following pass:
D:\WORK\eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25

But I need to find the pass from my Eclipse Plugin java code.

My second question is how can i get from code .classpath file of my BlackBerry project.

Regards,
Slavik.

Comment: Use the 101010 button to format your code as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the classpath entries from your IJavaProject, which you can get from your IProject something like this:

```
IJavaProject javaProject = (IJavaProject) JavaCore.create(project);
```